# Downloads directory not working

Tags: downloads, home-directory

I am new to Ubuntu operating system.

I went through this post : [Downloads Directory Not Opening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633451/downloads-directory-not-opening).

I have the same problem but the solution that was suggested there is not working.

Whatever changes I add using `xdg-user-dirs-update --set DOWNLOAD $HOME/Downloads` get erased when I reboot the computer. How can I fix this ? Is it possible to recover data in `Downloads` folder?

Comment: What does `ls -l ~/Downloads` show ?

Comment: I created ~/Downloads and now definitely its size is 0. I want my  XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR to point to "$HOME/Downloads"

Comment: Did you try updating `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the *Downloads* directory, type in Terminal: 
`mkdir ~/Downloads`

Then update *user-dirs.defaults* by typing in Terminal: 
`xdg-user-dirs-update --set DOWNLOAD $HOME/Downloads`

**EDITED** 
A possible solution is to prevent xdg-user-dirs-update from running (and resetting your configuration at each session start up) by setting `enabled=False` to your user-dirs.conf:
Edit this file:
`/etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf` 
And change `enabled=True` To `enabled=False`

Comment: Still cat .config/user-dirs.dirs remains same after reboot  XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/"

Comment: Ohhk, this is working. Any idea how I can recover my earlier files present in the location ?

Answer (score 0):

First, reboot.

If you don't have a ~/Downloads directory, just create it like so:

```
mkdir Downloads
```

This should remain over a reboot.