# Restarted & now --> '/home/USER/Documents': No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, reboot, openvpn

Newbie. Running Ubuntu 14.04 on an Acer Aspire (E11).
All fine until I restarted today and then received this message when trying to access any of my files (thru 'Bookmarks'; all my programs are running fine though):

```
Unhandled error message: Error when getting information for file
'/home/me/Documents': No such file or directory
```

I'm also an idiot and hadn't backed anything up so... yeah. f- me. Anyway, my HD shows that it's half full, so I imagine all my files haven't been deleted and that maybe it's just an issue of directories being lost (I needed a VPN installed on my computer for work -- the resident techie, not too familiar with Ubuntu, did it -- and it was after this that I rebooted and....).

Can anyone please help? Much appreciated!!!

Comment: While not a boot issue, post link to this. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info It posts copies of fstab, mounts, UUIDs and lots of info which will help. Otherwise we have to request each of those as separate commands.

Comment: It's probably something like this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/633451/downloads-directory-not-opening

Answer (score 0):

Did you look in your Trash for your Documents folder?

There's a possibility that the folder accidentally got moved into another folder. Have you done a search for "Documents", or for one of your files?

There's also a slight possibility that the Documents folder got renamed, or the name set to nothing. Open the Files app from the launcher, and it'll be in your home folder. Look for a folder with no name, or with some name that's a part of "Documents" like "Do". If you find such a folder, look inside and see if your documents are there. If so, just rename the folder back to "Documents" and you should be fine.

If the Files app doesn't show you such a folder, you'll need to use the "Terminal" app to look at it. Are you familiar with Terminal? To start, enter Terminal and type "ls -al" without the quotes, and look for a folder as I described earlier. If you need more help, please ask.

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?